# xmlHttp string passing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

the current xmlhttp function i am using is passing a very tiny int to the php file for processing using the GET method.

```
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlhttp==null)
        {
            alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
            return;
        }
        var url="user_submit.php";
        url=url+"?vote="+value;
        url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        function stateChanged()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
          {
          document.getElementById("captionbox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
```

now i want to process a `comment` box in this ajax request, which i suppose would require a POST call? can anyone help me with this?

i need to send the contents of the comment box through this ajax request to the php file for processing and then adding into the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#send()) to send POST data this way. You then have to send the right headers and encode that data correctly, etc.

That being said, it's incredibly tedious using `XmlHttpRequest`. There are cross-browser issues to consider (eg fallbacks for when `XmlHttpRequest` doesn't exist) and as you can see the code itself is messy.

Consider using a Javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead and then it reduces your code to:

```
$("#captionbox").load('user_submit.php', {
  vote: value,
  sid: 12345
});
```

which will also do the encoding of query string parameters (and many other things) correctly out of the box.

To post a comment, imagine you have:

```
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="send" value="Send">
```

then:

```
$.post("post_comment.php", {
  comment: $("#comment").text()
});
```

And jQuery is only 19K minified and gzipped.

Comment: I'd also agree with cletus, use a library if you don't feel like drudging up your good ol' AJAX functions (like I just did for you)

Comment: that was great. can you tell me how do i receive data i just sent into php?

Comment: The first example shows receiving HTML from PHP and putting it into a comment box. All jquery Ajax calls take a function callback where you can pass HTML, XML or JSON data back from the server.

Comment: what i mean is in my code i receive a variable 'vote' into user_submit.php. but in the jquery example, how should i receive daya into user_submit.php?

Comment: What is daya? Perhaps you should pose a second question explaining exactly what you want to do rather than trying to do this in comments or revising the old question.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
var url="user_submit.php",
    data="vote="+value+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
...
xmlHttp.send( data );
...
```

Comment: the above code when added raises this error in Firebug. uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/roadies/JS/script.js :: anonymous :: line 91" data: no]

Comment: you have to do more than copy paste it, you have to change the `...` to what your code is